# Float function does not return float value

Tags: c, function, floating-point, return-value, integer-arithmetic

I have programmed two simple functions. I want the user to write a integer value and the program finds the outputs from these two functions. Here's how the code looks like,

```
#include <stdio.h>

float f(int x) {
    
    return ((x * (x-2)) / 2);   
}

float g(int x) {
    
    return (x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) / 3);
}

int main() {
    
    int i;
    float f0, g0;
    
    scanf("%d", &i);
    
    f0 = f(i);
    g0 = g(i);
    
    printf("f(%d) = %0.2f , g(%d) = %0.2f", i, f0, i, g0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have created `float` functions but when I enter `5`, the `f` function is supposed to give me `7.5` but instead I have `7` as output.

How can I solve this?

Comment: göktuğ, Why did you select `float` rather than `double`?

Comment: As posted, `f(5)` should produce `7.00` as output and you want `7.50`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the both these expressions in the return statements

```
return ((x * (x-2)) / 2);   
return (x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) / 3);
```

there is used the integer arithmetic.

Change these statements like for example

```
return ((x * (x-2)) / 2.0f);   
return (x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) / 3.0f);
```

or

```
return (( ( float )x * (x-2)) / 2);   
return (( float )x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) / 3);
```

Comment: @göktuğ Select the answer as the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)

Comment: Good choice to use `2.0f` rather than `2.0` for a `float` result.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i don't think your answer is best one

Comment: @user55924 pros and cons either way.  Using `float x` avoids overflow, yet loses precision.

Comment: @göktuğ Select _any_ answer and your reputation will be increased.  No rush.

Comment: @user55924 I was not doubt that your answers are always best.:)

Comment: The first solution will cause integer overflow for relatively small values of `x`, the second one is less fragile but still fails for `INT_MIN`. Changing the argument and return types to `double` is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

```
float f(float x){
    
    return ((x * (x-2)) / 2);   
}

float g(float x){
    
    return (x * (x - 1) * (x - 2) / 3);
}
```

Hi. please remove int and put the float in the parameters

Comment: Your answer shows a better solution to the OP's problem, but you did not provide an explanation of the problem caused by integer arithmetics.  I am going to upvote both answers, but a good answer should both explain the problems and give one of more solutions.

Comment: Changing both functions to take and return `double` type is even better.